# Changing the timezone on a RHEL5/CentOS system

Tags: linux, redhat, timezone

How do I change the timezone on a RHEL5 system? I'm reading the instructions here - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-change-setup-timezone-tz-variable/

But they seem very bold (altering the /etc/localtime file).

Is this an acceptable practice (steps from link below):

```
Generic procedure to change timezone
Change directory to /etc
# cd /etc
Create a symlink to file localtime:
# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST localtime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what I did to an RHEL5 box two days ago, and it worked fine (with the difference that I hard-linked the file, not soft-linked, but I don't see there should be much difference).

If there is already a localtime file in place it is perhaps best to move the old one aside and put the new one in place in one operation:

```
cd /etc; mv localtime localtime.orig; ln /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST localtime
```

Comment: Did that - seems to work out fine...

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

It works, but the traditional RedHat way is to use a system-config-* utility. In this case, it'd be **system-config-time**.

**timeconfig** also does the job.

Comment: Your point is copmpletely fair and accurate, but I tend to prefer to do things in a non-distro-specific way if at all possible.  The recipe above should work on all linuces, and probably solaris and a few other POSIXy unices too.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the symlink method for years, but that's the wrong way. Because when the tzdata package gets updated the symlink gets blown away. Instead:

1. set the wanted zone in the file `/etc/sysconfig/clock`
   where the zone= value is the filename for the zone you want from /usr/share/zoneinfo, but without that full path. For instance: zone="America/Chicago"
2. `rm /etc/localtime`
3. `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime`

   using Chicago is just an example.
4. `date`